# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException for setMenuVisibility() in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm using setMenuVisibility() method in my fragments.

```
 @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);

        if (menuVisible) {
            Toast.makeText(Global.getGcontext(), "Hot",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}
```

I have 3 fragments in my project and when I move from fragment1 to fragment3 
I get this error:

```js
   11-28 17:54:26.678    3777-3777/ir.keeyow.alaki E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.keeyow.alaki, PID: 3777
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ir.keeyow.alaki.ir.keeyow.alaki.app.HotAlakiFragment.setMenuVisibility(HotAlakiFragment.java:233)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:149)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:802)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:433)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
            at com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip$2.onClick(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:240)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Unless `makeText()` is returning `null`, your stack trace is not possible from the code that you are showing here.

Comment: Global.getGContext() could be null?

Comment: @zgc7009: No, that would result in a `NullPointerException` somewhere *inside* `makeText()`. The stack trace says that the exception is occurring directly in `HotAlakiFragment.setMenuVisibility()`. That requires the code to be calling a method on `null` directly. `super` cannot be `null`, `Toast` cannot be `null`, and I am assuming that `Global` is a class and therefore cannot be `null`. That leaves the result of `makeText()` as the only thing that I can see that could be `null` that the code could be calling a method on.

Comment: when I remove Toast.makeText(Global.getGcontext(), "Hot",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and I use every thing like jsonObject.put("user_id", userinfo.getUserId()); same error occur for this line.

Comment: where are you calling HotAlakiFragment.setMenuVisibility(..) from issue must be there. provide the caller method.